# unable to set the onAction property of the button class error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to assign a function to a button. This seems to work sometimes and sometimes I get the error "unable to set the onAction property of the button class"

```
Windows("MyFile.XLS").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("G12").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(306, 36.6, 94.8, 21).Select
    Selection.OnAction = "'SomeFile.xls'!PrintWorkbook.PrintWorkbook"
    Selection.Characters.Text = "Print Workbook"
    With Selection.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=14).Font
        .Name = "Times New Roman"
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 10
    End With
```

I get the error on this line `"Selection.OnAction = "'SomeFile.xls'!PrintWorkbook.PrintWorkbook""`. Not sure why this only happens sometimes and works other times.

Comment: anyone other suggestions? i still haven't been able to fix this error

Answer (score 1):

Your code assumes that the button is selected after a call to `ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add` and that the selection succeeded.
You should use the return value of the `ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add` as shown below:

```
Windows("MyFile.XLS").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Range("G12").Select
        Set Button = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(306, 36.6, 94.8, 21)
        Button.OnAction = "'SomeFile.xls'!PrintWorkbook.PrintWorkbook"
        Button.Characters.Text = "Print Workbook"
        With Button.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=14).Font
            .Name = "Times New Roman"
            .FontStyle = "Bold"
            .Size = 10
        End With
```

Comment: Could it be a case that you already have a button binded to a same 'onAction' handler ?

Comment: no this is the first button im creating in this file. I am creating another one after this with the same code as above but that works fine. the error has something to do with the printworkbook function

Comment: Is you file macro enabled? try saving as xlsm.

Comment: Please try to put the macro in the same file. I see that macro is located at SomeFile.xls and the active file is MyFile.XLS